# How to write connection string for .asp page to sql server SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2

I have creates a page `webconfig.asp`. This page provide connection strings to whole ASP web site. But I do not know how to to give connection string .

I did this

```
Application("asd")="Data Source=PANKIL-PC\PANKIL;Initial Catalog=idoms;Integrated      Security=True; providerName=System.Data.SqlClient "
```

But this is not helpful. My application is getting timeout every time

Comment: is this .NET or classic asp question?

Comment: Which **edition** of SQL Server have you installed? Express, or a "full" edition (web, standard, developer, enterprise)? And also: what **instance name** have you given your installation? Nothing - just picked the defaults? Is there any other version of SQL Server installed on the same machine? Can you connect to your SQL Server using e.g. Management Studio? If so: what **server name** do you specify for that?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008 R2 is installed on machine. My .NET applications are working Fine but Classical ASP applications are not wolring.

Answer (score 0):

System.Data.SqlClient is for .net only as far as i know. use an oledb provider for classic asp like so:

```
constr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=PANKIL-PC\PANKIL;Initial Catalog=idoms;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

Comment: @PankilAgrawal well you have to add the user who executes the iis as a SQL Server user. i thought you have done this because you want to connect to sql server by integrated security

Comment: But I am not getting suceess